# Cloning repositories using mercurial eclipse not working on macos 10.8.2

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, osx-mountain-lion, osx-leopard

I am updated my mac os 10.7.4 to 10.8.2(osx-mountain-lion) . After updated macos I am unable to clone repositories from eclipse . I got the below error .

I am using `Mercurial-Eclipse-1.9.4` .

```
  hg -y clone --noupdate ssh://integ-build3//advent/hg/zohomailclient zohomailclient
remote: Permission denied, please try again.
remote: Permission denied, please try again.
remote: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password).
abort: no suitable response from remote hg!
```

I already put ssh-askpass on my 10.7.4 . It working fine on macos 10.7.4 after I put ssh-askpass . But, It not works on macos 10.8.2 .

when cloning password prompt was not prompted for `ssh cloning` via eclipse . It works for http clone .

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue lies with the ssh configuration on your upgraded environment rather than Mercurial or MercurialEclipse. To use MercurialEclipse with ssh, non-interactive ssh login needs to be configured. You should be able to ssh into that machine without it asking for a username/password.

Comment: Your solution will be a key-pairing ?. I can't do key-pairing for all mercurial repository  hosts . Is there any configuration change on macos will be fine .

Comment: I have not used ssh-askpass before but that should work too. So long as mercurial/ssh doesn't ask for the username and password on the commandline.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand ssh-askpass depends on X11 and 10.8 does not ship with X11. Maybe installing [XQuartz](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/) will help?